# Centering text element with border (using bootstrap) but border around text keeps changing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hey I have a text blurb that has a border around it. It wasn't centering properly (slightly off) before for whatever reason then I added position absolute, margin auto, and left,right 0; So now it is centered properly but the border around the text keeps changing (due to bootstrap). I'm using bootstrap to center it, and also because text-align center wasn't working. I want to border around it to stay at the padding that I set in my css, but idk what to do.

HTML & CSS Example Snippet:

```css
.col-port,
h2 {
  margin-top: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #D1946F;
}

.col-port {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border: solid;
  border-color: #D1946F;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  font-size: 21px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.col-port-cont {}

.col-port:hover {
  background: #D1946F;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-port-cont col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
  <a href="Portfolio.html">
    <p class="col-port">THE COLLECTION PORTFOLIO</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: On the `.col-port` class change the `display` property from **inline** to **block** and you can then remove all the positioning rules. It isn't clear what you mean about the padding issue though, posting an image would be helpful.

Comment: I think if you run the code snippet you'll see what it looks like, then full screen it and you'll see the the padding between the text and the border (on the sides ) becomes larger as the browser size does

Comment: I don't want to get rid of the positioning because otherwise it doesn't center the text properly, unless there's another way to center it like I have here.

Comment: I think you're referring to the actual width of the column, not the padding being applied to the paragraph tag. If that's the case you can adjust the column size you're using or avoid using columns altogether and simply create a using `max-width`.

Comment: That works but now for whatever reason the text moves up a bunch, like it is now above elements it should be below